# setup software with visual studio 2012 and install shield 2010

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-2012, installation, installshield

I have developed an application with Visual Studio 2012. I have also created a setup.exe with Install Shield 2010 Premium for my application. My development environment is Windows 8 64-bit, the application is compiled under Release Win32. The developing language is C++.

After building setup.exe, I ran it on another computer that is running on Windows 7 64-bit. An error message box pops up saying MSVCP110.dll is missing or not configured to run on Windows. Any ideas as to why this may be?

I tried installing Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 (http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=30679), but it still gives the same error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSVCP110.dll is really part of VC++ Redistributable package.

Try to install both versions of them: x86 and x64 if your machine is 64 bit.
For 32bit machine you need only x86 package.

Comment: Really weird, but suddenly works now... Thanks for your answer anyway.